# Having trouble with displaying parts of an array obtained from a JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, steam

I'm currently messing around with JSON. I have to variables: $a and $b.

$a retrieves a JSON file from a website:

```
    $a = file_get_contents("http://backpack.tf/api/IGetUsers/v2/?steamids=76561198037411448&format=json");
```

$b decodes it

```
    $b = json_decode($a, true);
```

I did var_dump on $b to confirm that it is, in fact, an array.

I attempted to echo $b["name"], but nothing was returned.

I have no clue what's wrong; nothing is being returned.

Comment: Maybe gettype() will help you: http://php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php

Comment: Try using var_dump($b) to get an idea of the contents of the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multidimensional set of data, instead of *$b["name"]* What you want is:

```
$b["response"]["players"][0]["name"]
```

This is the json objects structure from that URL

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1369778504,
        "players": {
            "0": {
                "steamid": "76561198037411448",
                "success": 1,
                "backpack_value": 185.86,
                "backpack_update": 1369543543,
                "name": "Paranoid Android",
                "stats_tf_reputation": 1,
                "notifications": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need iteration, will have to loop through *$b["response"]["players"]*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this? I'm only guessing that there could be more than 1 player.

```
for($i = 0;$i<count($b["response"]["players"]);$i++)
{
   echo $b["response"]["players"][$i]["name"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the JSON that is returned:

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1369778435,
        "players": {
            "0": {
                "steamid": "76561198037411448",
                "success": 1,
                "backpack_value": 185.86,
                "backpack_update": 1369543543,
                "name": "Paranoid Android",
                "stats_tf_reputation": 1,
                "notifications": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `$b = json_decode($a)`, then simply using `$b['name']` will not work. That key is not set.

You will have to follow the nesting of object literals. Something like this should work:

```
echo $b['response']['players']['0']['name'];
```